# How can I make sure TCL doesn't mess up the order of array elements?

Tags: arrays, tcl

The problem is that the order in which I "insert" elements in an array changes throughout the execution of the script.

Here is a quick reproduction of the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
# : \
exec /home/binops/afse/eer/eer_SPI-7.3.1/tclsh "$0" "$@"

proc myProc { theArray } {
  upvar $theArray theArrayInside
  parray theArrayInside
  puts "------"
  foreach { key value } [array get theArrayInside] {
    puts "$key => $value"
  }
}

# MAIN
set myArray(AQHI) AQHI
set myArray(O3) 1
set myArray(NO2) 2
set myArray(PM2.5) 3

parray myArray
puts "------"
myProc myArray
```

Output is:

```
myArray(AQHI)  = AQHI
myArray(NO2)   = 2
myArray(O3)    = 1
myArray(PM2.5) = 3
------
theArrayInside(AQHI)  = AQHI
theArrayInside(NO2)   = 2
theArrayInside(O3)    = 1
theArrayInside(PM2.5) = 3
------
PM2.5 => 3
O3 => 1
NO2 => 2
AQHI => AQHI
```

Notice I didn't use generic keys like A, B, C and generic values like 1, 2, 3, as you may have expected. This is because the order isn't messed up with these generic keys/values. Maybe this can help identify the problem.

Also notice that the initial order (AQHI, O3, NO2, PM2.5) is lost even at the first call to `parray` (order is now AQHI, NO2, O3, PM2.5; alphabetically sorted?). It is then changed again upon calling `array get ...` (inversed?)

So anyways, the question is: How can I make sure the initial order is kept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl is flexible enough that one can devise many schemes to handle what you want.  Here's an idea that stores the order of your keys within the array itself, assuming the empty string is not a valid key in your data:

```
proc array_add {ary_name key value} {
    upvar 1 $ary_name ary
    set ary($key) $value
    lappend ary() $key
}

proc array_foreach {var_name ary_name script} {
    upvar 1 $var_name var
    upvar 1 $ary_name ary
    foreach var $ary() {
        uplevel 1 $script
    }
}

array_add a foo bar
array_add a baz qux
array_add a abc def
array_add a ghi jkl

array_foreach key a {puts "$key -> $a($key)"}
# foo -> bar
# baz -> qux
# abc -> def
# ghi -> jkl

array names a
# ghi {} foo baz abc

array get a
# ghi jkl {} {foo baz abc ghi} foo bar baz qux abc def

parray a
# a()    = foo baz abc ghi
# a(abc) = def
# a(baz) = qux
# a(foo) = bar
# a(ghi) = jkl
```

Comment: Using this method, how would you go about finding the key of a certain value?

Comment: @Shawn, here's one way: `foreach {key val} [array get ary] {if {$val == $search} {puts $key; break}}`

Comment: Got it, I ended up using `proc array_getKeyFromValue { array_name value } { upvar 1 $array_name theArray; set returnValue ""; array_foreach key theArray { if { $theArray($key) == $value } { set returnValue $key; } } return $returnValue; }`

Answer (score 8):

You're making the mistake of equating Tcl arrays to those in a language like C, where it's a list of elements. Instead, Tcl arrays are maps (from a key to a value) like a HashMap in Java, and the order of elements is not preserved.

You may be better off using a list (if you just have a number of items you need to store in order).

If you're using 8.5 or higher, a [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/dict.htm) if you actually have a mapping of keys to values, since dictionaries are order preserving maps. There are dict backports to Tcl versions before 8.5, but I'm not sure whether they preserve order (and they're slower).

If you can't use 8.5 dicts and need key/value pairs, one option is to use a list of key value pairs and then use lsearch to pull out the values you need

```
> set mylist {{key1 value1} {key2 value2} {key3 value3}}
> lsearch -index 0 $mylist key2
0
> lindex $mylist [list [lsearch -index 0 $mylist key2] 1]
> value2
> proc kv_lookup {dictList key} {
      set index [lsearch -index 0 $dictList $key]
      if {$index < 0} {
          error "Key '$key' not found in list $dictList"
      }
      return [lindex $dictList [list $index 1]]
  }
> kv_lookup $mylist key2
value2
```

Man pages for 8.4 are [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/)

You may also want to look at this page on [keyed lists](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2519) for Tcl. It implements what I mentioned above, plus some other useful commands.

For an example of the different between an ordered "map" and an unordered one, you can take a look at the two java classes [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (unordered) and [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) (ordered).

Comment: @RHSeeger : I'm stuck with 8.4. And I use an array because what I really want is a map! Sure there isn't a way of doing this? Also, am I correct in assuming that `parray` prints out the array sorted alphabetically on keys? I can't find it in documentation, but my tests seem to indicate that this is the case...

Comment: How can I use a list to store the contents of a map like this: { AQHI => AQHI, O3 => 1, NO2 => 2, PM2.5 => 3 } It seems to me a list would not work. Or should I use two lists (one for keys, one for values) and make the key => value association using the indeces?

Comment: @Shawn: I was in the process of adding a description of how to handle ordered key/value pairs when you commented, actually. I also added a link to the 8.4 man pages for you.

Comment: @Shawn: `parray` prints the elements with the keys in simple sorted order (it uses `lsort [array names ary]` under the hood) though this is indeed not documented; it doesn't produce output that is (simply) consumable by other Tcl command as it's for debugging. It's also a simple procedure; `info body parray` will tell you exactly how it does its magic.

Comment: The pure Tcl implementation of the dict functionality doesn't preserve order. IIRC, there's also a C implementation (for 8.4 only; earlier versions can't use it, later don't need it) which _might_ preserve insertion order, but I've not checked it; I know it's based on the same code, but it might have been forked before I added the order stabilization.

Comment: While I was crafting an answer for this question using keyed list, I ran across this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216471/keylset-bug-in-tcl-8-4-and-8-5

Comment: @Hai Vu : Too bad! keylset looked like a viable solution

Comment: The keyl::set implementation in pure Tcl on that page does not have the 'problem' described in Hai's link. The word problem is in quotes because it's not a bug, it was a design decision made by the Tclx creator(s). The decision made by the person who posted the pure Tcl code was different.

Comment: @Donal Fellows : How does array get work under the hood? I can't beleive it scrambles up the order on purpose, so why not simply leave the order as is? In other words, what make the order change?

Comment: @Shawn: The problem is that arrays are hash maps and aren't stored in any particular order. The [array get] command doesn't change the order from the order you inserted in, it changes it from the random order they're found in. While it's possible to have an order hashmap, it generally isn't the standard implementation for languages, since it costs more to do so.

Comment: @RHSeeger : Hash maps, right. I was thinking along the lines of C-style arrays, were all the elements are stored contiguously in memory (Is that correct?)

Comment: @Shawn : Yes, in C arrays are the equivalent (more or less) to Tcl lists... an ordered list of items. Its the fact that you need an ordered list of mappings from key to value and the ability to look things up by key that make life somewhat more complicated. One of the nice things about Java is that it has so many different data structures in it's standard library. For many languages, you need to go to external libraries to get some of the less common structures (like an ordered map).