# keylset bug in Tcl 8.4 and 8.5?

Tags: tcl

Consider the following simple exercise:

```
package require Tclx
keylset myArray "v1.5" "ready"
puts $myArray
```

The expected output:

```
{v1.5 ready}
```

The actual output:

```
{v1 {{5 ready}}}
```

My questions are

1. This seems to be an error in keylset, I have confirmed this behavior on both 8.4 and 8.5
2. How do I get around it? I have tried several ways to quote the key to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. :)
Dot is a hierarchical key separator in keyed list.

See the example for explanation:

```
keylset myArray {v1.5} "ready" {v1.6} "empty"

puts $myArray                ;# ==> {v1 {{5 ready} {6 empty}}}
puts [keylget myArray v1]    ;# ==> {5 ready} {6 empty}
puts [keylget myArray v1.5]  ;# ==> ready
puts [keylget myArray v1.6]  ;# ==> empty
```

Answer (score 1):

keylset is a Tclx command. I would really recommend you to take a look to the [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm) command from Tcl 8.5

Comment: Thanks, Carlos, but in my case, our system is still 8.4 and installing the dict back-port is not an option.

Comment: There are a few differences too; in particular the syntax is quite different, both of the map value (keyed list, dict) and of the access commands. Also, keyed lists are technically multimaps – you can have multiple instances of the same key at the same level – whereas dicts are strict about enforcing uniqueness of keys.